# Fetch Json from MySQL in Jquery calender

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json

**I have data in my DB in JSON format in the DB>test (Table)**

```
   [{
    "day": 0,
    "periods": []
}, {
    "day": 1,
    "periods": [{
        "start": "01:45",
        "end": "07:45",
        "title": ""
    }]
}, {
    "day": 2,
    "periods": [{
        "start": "02:45",
        "end": "07:45",
        "title": ""
    }]
}, {
    "day": 3,
    "periods": [{
        "start": "01:45",
        "end": "07:15",
        "title": ""
    }]
}, {
    "day": 4,
    "periods": [{
        "start": "04:45",
        "end": "09:45",
        "title": ""
    }]
}, {
    "day": 5,
    "periods": []
}, {
    "day": 6,
    "periods": []
}]
```

I want to fetch this in Jquery scheduler which looks like this:

```
<script>
$(function () {
  $("#schedule3").jqs({ 

  });
</script>
```

My problem is that i am unable to fetch the saved json values in my mySQL database and display it on the jQuery scheduler.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm6ve.png)
Below is my code for the import.php:

```
$selected = mysqli_select_db($conn,"db") 
$fetch_port_relation = "SELECT * FROM `test`";
$result_port_relation = $conn->query($fetch_port_relation);
if ($result_port_relation->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($ios_row = $result_port_relation->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data = $ios_row['test'];
    $jsondata = json_decode($data);
    $jsondata->day; //this returns
    print_r($data);
    foreach($jsondata->periods as $periods) {
    echo $periods->start;
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: You need to explain more. What is your problem, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi Alex, I am stuck in fetching the jSon data from mySQL (I am able to fetch it but unable to decode the same) and fetch it in the front end of jQuery weekly scheduler script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Depends on the programming language you are using, if you're using Java/php, create a service method which would get the JSON from the database and return the JSONobject through ajax, and introduce it into the calendar through jquery javascript.

i would also recommend you to use full calendar as its very easy to grasp.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

    eventSources: [

        // your event source
        {
            url: '/myfeed.php', // use the `url` property
            color: 'yellow',    // an option!
            textColor: 'black'  // an option!
        }

        // any other sources...

    ]
});
```

my Feed would return the json object.

Comment: Hi Farhan, Thanks for the reply. I need only weekly scheduler, I dont need month and year in the calendar, I checked the full calendar and dint know how to start with. Can you please suggest

Comment: Yes, you can use the weekly view of the full calendar, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/


This is the link to get you started on a basic level, it has options of weekly view, daily view, on click events etc. If you need help on a specific level, feel free to ask me.